# Counting numbers and sizes

Tags: grammatical-number

I have a question about counting numbers and sizes. Examples I've thought of are when you are ordering food at a fast food restaurant.

If I want to order #6 on the menu, which should I say?

> Can I have three number *sixes*?
>   I'll have *three of* number six?
>   I'll have *three of* number *sixes*?

When they ask how many drinks I want, how should I answer?

> I'll have three *larges*-
>   I'll have three *large*-

"Larges" sound so awkward, but it feels like I should be using plural here.

Can you count colors? Do you say "I bought two *reds*" or "I bought *two of the reds*"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better answer might come along to explain why, but

"Can I have three number sixes?" or "I'll have three of number six" are both correct. "I'll have three of number sixes" is not standard English.

When ordering drinks, I'd use something like "I'll have three large coffees". "I'll have three larges" is fine gramatically but doesn't sound right to me without context; it might make sense when you're just getting an empty cup and you're going to take it to the soda fountain to fill it yourself. "I'll have three large" is not standard.

On counting colors, I'd use "I bought two red ones" or "I bought two of the red ones". The second phrase implies you and the person you're speaking to know which group of red ones you bought two of.

Comment: How about "I'll have three large ones." when ordering drinks? Sounds right and is grammatically correct.

Answer (score 1):

In the first examples, I would say

> Can I have three number sixes?

or

> I'll have three of **the** number sixes.

*the* is needed as an article for the noun, a definite article since we know its order #6.

*I'll have three larges.* is OK, but *I'll have three large.* is not. Here, by writing *large* we know its not a noun (as a noun it would be plural as in the first example). So we need a noun to be added, as in

> I'll have three large **drinks**.

As for counting reds, red is usually an adjective, not a noun. When it its used as noun, it is implied in context to mean red (something).
I think your examples are grammatically correct, but I think its better to add what's red

> I bought two red roses
>   I bought two of the red roses